# Insert multiple rows taking values from string passed as input to stored proc

Tags: mysql

I have condition like, multiple values will be passed to stored proc as string. For example if the string consists like INput1:'1,2,3,' and INput2:'a,b,c,' then the insert into table should be done in the below manner:
First row:-column1:1, column2:a 
Second row:-column1:2, column2:b
Third row:-column1:3, column2:c

I am new to this, so can some assist me in this.

Comment: Practically speaking, there is no "order" of inserting records into a SQL database.  Just insert, and let the database worry about it.  Behind the scenes maybe there is some index action happening or maybe not.

Comment: How can I insert multiple rows taking the string.